# Check if an URL exists with Javascript with a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, url, firefox-addon

I'd like to check if a given URL exists using Javascript with a Firefox extension.

Comment: @gnur I mean exists on the Web (if you type it on the adress bar you access the website).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to try loading the URL - use XMLHttpRequest for that:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url);
request.onload = function()
{
    if ((request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) || request.status == 304)
        alert("Exists!");
    else
        alert("HTTP response isn't success, URL doesn't exist or is currently unavailable");
};
request.onerror = function()
{
    alert("Loading URL errored out, server doesn't exist or is currently unavailable");
};
request.send(null);
```

Comment: This will not work because of the cross site scripting restrictions, it will always say it isn't available if the url is outside the scripts domain.

Comment: @gnur: The question is about Firefox extensions, there are no restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ( which is the one accepted this times ;-) )